# How to make all buttons have same width

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

My Requirement is to make all the buttons i.e., "BRISBANE","MELBOURNE", "CANBERRA", "SYDNEY" buttons including 50:50 and Reset are of same width. Please have a look at the image below where all the answer buttons have different widths.  [image]

Output Should look like below (ignore green colour for answer buttons) :

[image]

Below is my current code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Which is the capital of Australia?"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="BRISBANE"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="CANBERRA"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="MELBOURNE"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="SYDNEY"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="50:50"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="RESET"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me achieve this! Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: In _LinearLayout_, you can do this programmatically. It would be easier, however, to do this in _ConstraintLayout_. Is the use of _LinearLayout_ a requirement?

Comment: I don't understand your question, Do you mean you want all buttons to have the same width? You can fix the size in the XML code?

Comment: @Cheticamp Yes, Using LinearLayout is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Place the buttons in a *LinearLayout* that wraps its contents. Assign each button a width of `match_parent`. The buttons should all assume the width of the widest button. See below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BRISBANE" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CANBERRA" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MELBOURNE" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SYDNEY" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

[image]

This will work for the "answer" buttons. If the two command buttons need to be the same size, you will likely need to do those programmatically.